# select query with many-on-many table

Tags: sql, select

I Have a table dbo.ArtikelAlternatief created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ArtikelAlternatief]( 
    [Barcode] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [BarcodeAlternatief] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,   
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ArtikelAlternatief] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Barcode] ASC,
    [BarcodeAlternatief] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Now I want the following results combined:

```
select BarcodeAlternatief AS 'Barcode' from dbo.ArtikelAlternatief where Barcode like '7630015711115' 
select Barcode AS 'Barcode' from dbo.ArtikelAlternatief where BarcodeAlternatief like '7630015711115'
```

How is it possible to combine those 2 query's in one result column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in 3 methods.

### [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e7574a/5)

**Method 1:**
Using `CASE` Statement:

```
select 
     (case when Barcode = '7630015711115' 
            then BarcodeAlternatief
            else Barcode END) as 'Barcode'  
    from ArtikelAlternatief
    where Barcode = '7630015711115'
          or BarcodeAlternatief = '7630015711115';
```

---

**Method 2:**
You can try using `DECODE` statement (Of oracle),

```
SELECT  DECODE (BarcodeAlternatief , '7630015711115', Barcode , BarcodeAlternatief ) AS Barcode 
FROM dbo.ArtikelAlternatief 
where Barcode = '7630015711115' OR BarcodeAlternatief = '7630015711115'
```

---

**Method 3:**

Try below query using `UNION ALL`:

```
select BarcodeAlternatief AS 'Barcode' from dbo.ArtikelAlternatief 
where Barcode = '7630015711115' 

UNION ALL

select Barcode AS 'Barcode' from dbo.ArtikelAlternatief 
where BarcodeAlternatief = '7630015711115'
```

1. If you wish to allow duplicates, then use `UNION ALL`. If you do not wish to allow duplicates, then use `UNION`.
2. In your case, you can use `=` operator instead of `LIKE` in where condition because you are not doing any pattern matching.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [UNION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) operator:

```
query1
UNION ALL
query2
```

The `ALL` keyword is optional, and used if you want duplicate rows.

Answer (score 1):

U may try this

```
select BarcodeAlternatief AS 'Barcode' from dbo.ArtikelAlternatief where Barcode like '7630015711115' 

Union All

select Barcode AS 'Barcode' from dbo.ArtikelAlternatief where BarcodeAlternatief like '7630015711115'
```

Answer (score 1):

Put 'OR' and 'CASE' function condition :

```
select 
     (case when Barcode like '7630015711115' then BarcodeAlternatief
           when BarcodeAlternatief like '7630015711115' the Barcode 
            else '') as 'Barcode'  
    from dbo.ArtikelAlternatief
    where Barcode like '7630015711115'
          or BarcodeAlternatief like '7630015711115'
```

Comment: Please, try and verify with expected output